# Including boost function.hpp, without using it, increases the size of my binary by 200k. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, embedded, std

I'm working on an embedded processor so binary size matters a lot. I am trying to avoid using the standard library. I'd like to use std::function, however. I extracted "function.hpp" from boost, and I'm trying to use that, but simply including function.hpp increases the size of my binary 200k, which makes it bigger than my processor can accept. If I include the standard library, it only increases my binary 60k. I can't figure it out, if I'm not using any of the templates yet, there shouldn't be any overhead. And even if I do, I can't imagine it's 200k worth of code. I'm using gcc 4.7, and I've disabled debugging info from what I can tell "-g0" and turned on optimizations "-O2".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Optimize more with `-O3`? (or `-Os` for size)

Comment: @Cornstalks That's exactly the wrong thing to do. `-O3` enables optimizations that can *increase* binary size. Either way, I don't think this is related to optimizations, I reckon that including the boost header makes the compiler pull in exception handling into your program whereas you're not using them otherwise. Which system/processor are you compiling for?

Comment: `-Os` shaves off a couple kb, (thanks for the tip) but not enough to matter. Compiling without exceptions, `-fno-exceptions` changes the size 5k, and adding exception support, adds the 5k back. Still doesn't make sense. I'm compiling for ARM Cortex m3. The other weird thing, is that I can use std::function from the standard library, actually use it in code, not just include it and it only adds 60k. You figure that would compile in the same exception handling that boost would.

Comment: Have you actually looked at what the function.hpp contains [I haven't, so I can't say] - and what does the compiled code actually contain - `objdump --disassemble prog` would give you disassembly of your program. Add `-S` to get the source-lines intermingled.

Comment: @us2012: Good points, thanks!

Comment: @MatsPetersson I did, it turns out it's including <functional> already, so I'm eating the standard library plus boost. That still means boost is taking 120k even if I don't use it. I guess my solution is to find a stand alone implementation of std::function. Still interested in why it's so expensive to use boost though.

Comment: Probably because it drags in a whole load of other things, that in turn drags in more stuff. This tends to be most noticeable when you DON'T use the libraries dragged in. Once you start actually adding in your code, it doesn't add that much, if you see what I mean.

Comment: The linker should not include code that is not referenced (in either library) unless you are forcing a "partial link" (-r or -Ur).  Are you sure this is the *binary size* rather than the *object code* size?  Check the linker map file output to see the *actual* size.

Comment: @Clifford yeah, it's binary size. The size of the binary image to load on the flash memory grows from 40k to 260k. It's odd. How would I look it up in the map, for curiosity's sake? I'm already producing one, by the way.

Comment: @KendrickTaylor:  In that case all the advice about stripping the symbol table is irrelevant. A map file typically has the size and location of each individual object and a summary table.  You might also generate a cross reference that tells you what references what which might tell you why things are unexpectedly included in the link.  The map output is controlled by linker options, I am not a habitual GNU gcc toolchain user at the moment so cannot advise further.  I am interested since I have a colleague advocating the use of Boost, arguing that it will not adversely affect code size.

Answer (score 2):

GCC includes some symbol information into the compiled binary even if you use `-g0`. In order to really get rid of all symbols one should use `--strip-all` command line option for the linker.

Also, since the size of the executable is important for you, consider `-fdata-sections` and `-ffunction-sections` for the compiler and `--gc-sections` for the linker.